# Realm occasionally notifies explicitly ignored observations

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a two-dimensional data source of shelves with items, and have implemented UICollectionView's drag and drop to move items between the shelves. When performing the drop, I manage the UI updates manually as Realm suggests, because change notifications aren't handled on the main thread.

To do this, I use the `commitWrite(withoutNotifying:)` API as described here https://academy.realm.io/posts/meetup-jp-simard-mastering-realm-notifications/.

My issue is that Realm will occasionally just ignore that call, and notify my observers anyway. That obviously leads to an UICollectionView internal inconsistency error as changes to the data source are applied twice.

I've proved this by logging the tokens I ignore in my write call, then just using lldb to spot what token triggered the crashing reload.

Here's one piece of code that triggers this. It also happens in similar logic.

```
var ignoredTokens = Set([shelfCell.token, shelvesToken])

realm.beginWrite()
coordinator.items.enumerated().forEach { (offset, dropItem) in
    guard let localObject = dropItem.dragItem.localObject as? ItemDragObject<ShelfModelType> else {
        return
    }

    guard let oldIndex = localObject.sourceShelf.items.index(of: localObject.sourceItem) else {
        return
    }
    let newIndex = targetedIndex + offset

    localObject.sourceShelf.items.remove(at: oldIndex)
    shelf.items.insert(localObject.sourceItem, at: newIndex)
    droppedItems.append((index: newIndex, dragItem: dropItem.dragItem))

    if let sourceCell = localObject.sourceCell, sourceCell.shelf == localObject.sourceShelf { // cell may have been reused
        draggedItems[sourceCell] = (draggedItems[sourceCell] ?? []) + [oldIndex]
        ignoredTokens.insert(sourceCell.token)
    }
}

print("CELL DROP IGNORING", ignoredTokens)
try! realm.commitWrite(withoutNotifying: ignoredTokens.compactMap { $0 })
```

To add to the fun, this doesn't happen consistently. It's getting really frustrating, what's going on here?

---

Edit: After extensive debugging, I am very sure there is something weird going on with Realm. I've performed the exact same action multiple times, checked that there's no other writes accidentally occurring at the same time (by printing inside the Realm code), and it fails after a while.

After some executions, the same write operation that didn't notify observers in the past, will notify those same observers. For runs that don't bug out, the latter two lines will not be printed.

```
HACK: Commiting write without notifying [<RLMCancellationToken: 0x2830a3e70>, <RLMCancellationToken: 0x2830b0840>, <RLMCancellationToken: 0x283163300>]
HACK: Ignored notification <RLMCancellationToken: 0x2830a3e70> in Shelf for change D: [] I: [3] M: []
HACK: Ignored notification <RLMCancellationToken: 0x283163300> in Shelf for change D: [1] I: [] M: []
```

Comment: This is going to be really tough to troubleshoot here on SO. There's nothing really really wrong with the code, other than (IMO) catching throws from commitWrite and handling via a do closure. That tell me that something outside the code is causing the issue possibly the ignoredTokes are not *all* of the tokens that should be ignored - perhaps there's a List property where one of the observed children is being modified, therefore firing the event? Oh, and why is ignoredTokens a set?

Comment: @Jay Yeah... I'm just really lost in figuring this one out so I thought I'd give SO a shot. You're right about `do-catch`, I was just lazy. I agree that it seems like the issue is elsewhere, but I've combed trough this hundreds of times now without finding any apparent culprit. The fact that is doesn't happen in any predicable manner and just randomly occurs leads me to think that it might be something wrong internally in Realm. It's a `Set` here because there was duplicate elements in Array and I wanted to see if that was the issue, it's back to an array now. Didn't make any difference.

Comment: Yeah, understand the frustration. One thing you could do is the run the code *without* the `withoutNotifying` and perform the same steps *with* the `withoutNotifying` and see if you can spot the difference in which objects are affected. If an object is affected with both runs that narrows down where the issue is; that object should not be firing off an event but it is.

Comment: @Jay Thank you, but I don't think that will help. I log every time a Realm notification is fired, and when the bug doesn't happen, no notifications are executed. If you are very into Realm and drag+drop, would you care to look over my entire logic and see if you can spot any obvious mistakes?

Comment: I would look at this line `try! realm.commitWrite(withoutNotifying: [cell.nameToken].compactMap { $0 })` and ensure cell.nameToken is what you think it is.

Comment: @Jay That line is correct :( I've sent a token to Realm support, let's hope they can enlighten me. Reallly defeating with issues like these

Comment: Heres a [Video](https://www.icloud.com/attachment/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fcvws.icloud-content.com%2FB%2FAY_DShOj81Rhib-jNjh-0Se7d3ZNAVqrNkpQSXPylTpQ_bbga6mTBNIX%2F%24{f}%3Fo%3DAnijQctJQ-MIV48uU1FdLDY3gqTqbJ-6HoVA8uTv1mw3%26v%3D1%26x%3D3%26a%3DCAogWtmwLZtpwEqHr07jfXA-UCwNFBYdoWpi1dztKckVZ9MSJxDj16KO6y0Y4-ed4vQtIgEAKggByAD_Aw8ASlIEu3d2TVoEkwTSFw%26e%3D1577532748%26k%3D%24{uk}%26fl%3D%26r%3D829C4881-D256-47B4-8BEA-4CACDFFCCC26-1%26ckc%3Dcom.apple.largeattachment%26ckz%3D78574261-5F39-4C8F-8525-5F50A89DB060%26p%3D59%26s%3D_uolJawXygVJLno0bt44vL99bDU&uk=bqwHhLLsFLnW7MIz6LCIGw&f=RealmBug.mov&sz=126874935)

Comment: Do you have any network requests that are running in the background that may be making changes to your data set? That would be my first suspicion. Also, what I would do if I were you is create a sample project using the same version of realm you are using on this project and see if you can reproduce it with a simple model or two and a button click. The last thing you may want to try is using `write(withoutNotifying:)` instead of `beginWrite()` and `commitWrite`

Comment: @Rob I don’t, Realm is the only networking active.. :/ Sample project is just ugh but I guess I should do that. I sent my entire codebase to Realm support so I’m hoping they can dig up something smart. From the source write(withoutNotifying:) does the exact same as begin and commit, so I don’t think that’d help either.

Comment: Good luck. Keep us posted. This is an interesting problem.

Comment: Kinda an update @Rob. My ticket has now been open for a month and I have not gotten any response in 24 days, even though I've been trying hard to get one. Regretting Realm a bit at the moment.